# Why doesn't my LIKE statement filter when using a parameter

Tags: entity-framework, t-sql, sql-like

When I use a LIKE clause in a query with embedded '%' characters, the query does not return expected rows. But if I use a constant string, it works as expected. This is only causing problems when I'm using *StartsWith* (`LIKE 'x%'`) rather than *Contains* (`LIKE '%x%'`).

What have I done wrong!??!

Repro code (the final query is unexpected):

```
DECLARE @p__linq__StartsWith nvarchar 
SET @p__linq__StartsWith = N'm%'
DECLARE @p__linq__Contains nvarchar
SET @p__linq__Contains = N'%m%'

-- OK: Returns "Me" and "Not Me"
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT N'Me' AS F UNION ALL SELECT N'Not Me' AS F) x
WHERE f LIKE N'%m%'

-- OK: Returns "Me"
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT N'Me' AS F UNION ALL SELECT N'Not Me' AS F) x
WHERE f LIKE N'm%'


-- OK: Returns "Me" and "Not Me"
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT N'Me' AS F UNION ALL SELECT N'Not Me' AS F) x
WHERE f LIKE @p__linq__Contains

-- Unexpected: Returns nothing
-- And why doesn't the last query do the same thing???
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT N'Me' AS F UNION ALL SELECT N'Not Me' AS F) x
WHERE f LIKE @p__linq__StartsWith
```

Environment: SQL generated by Entity Framework 5 against SQL Server 2012 SP1. Checked the same behaviour occurs on SQL 2000 and 2008R2 SP2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this at the end of your code:

```
print @p__linq__StartsWith
```

The result explain the unexpected result. Now try this code:

```
DECLARE @p__linq__StartsWith nvarchar(5)
SET @p__linq__StartsWith = N'm%'
DECLARE @p__linq__Contains nvarchar(5)
SET @p__linq__Contains = N'%m%'

-- OK: Returns "Me" and "Not Me"
SELECT * FROM (SELECT N'Me' AS F UNION ALL SELECT N'Not Me' AS F) x
WHERE f LIKE N'%m%'

-- OK: Returns "Me"
SELECT * FROM (SELECT N'Me' AS F UNION ALL SELECT N'Not Me' AS F) x
WHERE f LIKE N'm%'

-- OK: Returns "Me" and "Not Me"
SELECT * FROM (SELECT N'Me' AS F UNION ALL SELECT N'Not Me' AS F) x
WHERE f LIKE @p__linq__Contains

-- Unexpected: Returns nothing
-- And why doesn't the last query do the same thing???
SELECT * FROM  (SELECT N'Me' AS F UNION ALL SELECT N'Not Me' AS F) x
WHERE f LIKE @p__linq__StartsWith

print @p__linq__StartsWith
```

All you need is to specify the length of nvarchar to resolve this.

I found an explanation in BOL http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx. Look at the first remark.

Comment: So SQL Server assumes a length of 1 on (n)varchar if it is unspecified.

Comment: Do you have a reference on this assumption?

Comment: declare @a nvarchar
select @a = N'hello world'
select @a

Comment: Sorry, no reference, just observation based on your answer. Your previous comment demonstrates the behaviour well.